# % : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell, null

I think I've found unexplainable in PowerShell scripting. Let me describe the problem below:

I created a function that will query VSTS and will output back the amount of bugs that contain specific tags.

```cs
function GetBugsFromVSTS($applicationName, $first_url, $second_url, $query) {
    #Building the body of the HTTP request to VSTS endpoint
    $bodyOfRequest = $query | ConvertTo-Json

    #Building headers of the HTTP request to VSTS endpoint
    $headers = @{
        'Content-Type'='application/json'
        'Accept'='application/json'
        'Authorization' = '' + $vsts_access_token + ''
    }

    $getBugs = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $first_url `
               -Method Post `
               -Body $bodyOfRequest `
               -Headers $headers | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

    $json_decoded = $getBugs | ConvertFrom-Json

    if ($json_decoded.workItems -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "$applicationName Json decoded workitems are equal null" -ForegroundColor Red
    } else {
        Write-Host "$applicationName Json decoded workitems are not null" -ForegroundColor Green
        $json_decoded.workItems | % {
            $bug_id = $_.id
            Write-Host $bug_id
        }
    }

    $json_decoded.workItems | % {
        $bug_id = $_.id
        $url = ($second_url +$bug_id)

        $getVstsBugState = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $headers

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Application Name" = $applicationName
            "Id" = $bug_id;
            "State" = $getVstsBugState.fields.'System.State';
            "Reason" = $getVstsBugState.fields.'System.Reason';
            "Severity" = $getVstsBugState.fields.'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity'.Substring(4);
            "AssignedTo" = $getVstsBugState.fields.'System.AssignedTo'.displayName
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run it

```
    $application = "MyBeautifulApp"
    $application_first_url = "https://test.visualstudio.com/72L80E4b-1583-45c1-b669-d8de6133V895/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0"
    $application_second_url = "https://test.visualstudio.com/72L80E4b-1583-45c1-b669-d8de6133V895/_apis/wit/workItems/"
    $application_query = @{"query" = "SELECT [System.Id],[System.WorkItemType],[System.Title],[System.AssignedTo],[System.State] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' AND [System.Title] CONTAINS 'Test' AND [System.TAGS] CONTAINS 'Test'"}
    GetBugsFromVSTS $application $application_first_url $application_second_url $application_query
} catch {
    Write-Warning "##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]Some problem occured querying MyBeautifulApp application. Please see below for error details"
    $_
}
```

The most interesting part here is that I'm getting this really weird error message

> WARNING: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]Some problem occured
>   querying MyBeautifulApp application. Please see below for error
>   details
>
> % : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

For the sake of test I added `if..else` clause to test that `$json_decoded.workItems` are not equal null, and that verification passes. If I run the code, full output will be

```
MyBeautifulApp Json decoded workitems are not null
9805
10330
10331
10371
10372
10373
10374

WARNING: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]Some problem occured querying MyBeautifulApp application. Please see below for error details
% : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. line 29

+     $json_decoded.workItems | % {
+                               ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [ForEach-Object], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

How is it possible that the first verification for `$json_decoded.workItems` (**line 23**) is not indicating that variable equals null, whereas the second statement (**line 29**) shows that it's null?

Comment: The error appears to refer to the `ForEach-Object` part. Have you investigated `$getVstsBugState` to ensure it is also not null and contains the properties you are indexing into? `field.'System.State` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't `$json_decoded.workItems`, the problem happens *inside the script block passed to `%` / `ForEach-Object`*:

Since you're using an enclosing `try` / `catch` handler, the offending individual statement inside the block is, unfortunately, *not* pinpointed in the error message.

However, given that there's only *one* method call in your block, the offending line can be inferred:

```
"Severity" = $getVstsBugState.fields.'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity'.Substring(4);
```

In other words: `$getVstsBugState.fields.'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity'` evaluates to `$null`, which is why the `.Substring()` method call fails.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @TiredOfProgramming.